# ImportError: cannot import name 'webdriver'

Tags: python

I am a newbie for selenium python. I have installed python, pip etc.. 
I am trying to run the below code but it is showing error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'webdriver'

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
```

could anyone please solve this issue?

Answer (score 186):

If your file name is `selenium.py`, change it to something else and delete `.pyc` files or the `__pycache__` directory if exists.

If you do not have the selenium, you should install the `selenium` by using `pip` or `pipenv`:

```
pip install selenium
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: My answer is correct and solves the problem. Did you test it?

Comment: @MesutGüneş: The OP stated in a comment on the other answer: _"No I have not created selenium file."_ So, the solution you present here does not apply to the OP's problem.

Comment: Lol, comes handy when drunk!

Comment: worked for me as well, wouldn't have guessed this is such a common mistake

Comment: Nice solution. That's really funny LOL

Comment: Your answer solved my issue - I had a file called selenium.py in same directory :-)

Comment: **Same if your python script name is "signal.py", I am currently creating a script for signal and changed the name to signal.py and it didn't work anymore. I renamed it to "signalbot.py" and it was good.**

Comment: Omg, this happens even after years of programming experience. Logged in just to say thank you

Answer (score 23):

It says that webdriver cant be import.So I assume you have Selenium installed.

So I can only assume that the selenium lied in different place in your path.

Maybe you have accidently create a file named selenium ?

Comment: Two folders (selenium and selenium-2.45.0-py3.5.egg-info) are created in C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\Lib\site-packages path. Is this correct or I have done any mistakes during installation?

Comment: No I have not created selenium file. Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: import selenium ,and then print selenium.__file__ . give me the output

Comment: output is Finding files... done.
Importing test modules ... done.

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK

Comment: did you do that in python shell?

Comment: No, I did it in eclipse.

Comment: In eclipse the oupput is Finding files... done.
Importing test modules ... C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\Lib\site-packages\selenium\selenium.py
done.

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK 
and in python shell the output is 
C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\Lib\site-packages\selenium\__init__.py

Comment: did you see the **webdriver** folder under **site-packages\selenium** ? Is there a **__init__.py** file under **site-packages\selenium**  ?

Comment: Yes webdriver folder and __init__.py file is there under site-packages\selenium.

Comment: I cant find the solution. It seems like everything is good.Sorry

Answer (score 18):

1. if your file is selenium.py rename it.
2. Pay attention to have import Keys instead of import keys

Answer (score 8):

Step 1: First rename filename if saved with `selenium.py` and delete `selenium.pyc`.

`mv selenium.py test.py
rm selenium.pyc`

Step 2: import module selenium if not already installed.

`pip install selenium`

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by reinstalling the older version of selenium package because the newest version doesn't support Python 2.6.6 which in my case was installed and I didn't have root access to install the new one.

While the newest version of selenium package doesn't have support for Python 2.6.6, I had to downgrade by reinstalling the selenium package with lower version

```
pip uninstall selenium
pip install --user selenium==3.5.0
```

Comment: For windows pip there must be "==" instead of single "="

Answer (score 0):

Deepa, it is likely a 'path not found' issue. Add as many paths as relevant to help the IDE find selenium and webdriver. For example, on my Mac, I've added all the following paths so nothing is missed :

file:///Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5 file:///Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/plat-darwin file:///Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload file:///Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages file:///Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium-3.0.0b2/py file:///Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium-3.0.0b2/py/selenium file:///Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium-3.0.0b2/py/selenium/common file:///Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium-3.0.0b2/py/selenium/webdriver

Answer (score 0):

I have deleted *pycache* folder and renamed to my py file, now it works without any error.