# Learning Selenium and getting ImportError: cannot import name webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I created a virtualenv with the required packages.  Activated the env.  Now I keep getting the following: `ImportError: cannot import name webdriver`.  I've checked my env and all of my files seem to be right.  Can anyone offer input?  I'm including a code drop link and screenshot.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1jzVoBilX9pU3CYC2czQ3IBRE87sCWJ3k

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver    # this is the offending line
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException


def init_driver():
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
    return driver


def lookup(driver, query):
    driver.get("http://www.google.com")
    try:
        box = driver.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
            (By.NAME, "q")))
        button = driver.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
            (By.NAME, "btnK")))
        box.send_keys(query)
        button.click()
    except TimeoutException:
        print("Box or Button not found in google.com")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    driver = init_driver()
    lookup(driver, "Selenium")
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.quit()
```

[image: Image of error]

Comment: Just added the code...

Comment: change your current file name to something other than `selenium.py`. Python is looking for webdriver in your own code which it can't find to import, instead of going to the actual `selenium.py` to look for..

Comment: I renamed it to magnolia.py and initialized the code.  I still got this error.  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/josh.frazier/Desktop/python_play/env/magnolia.py", line 2, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
ImportError: cannot import name webdriver
[Finished in 0.042s]

Comment: are there any other files named `selenium.py`?

Comment: Tehre is a selenium.pyc file in the env

Comment: delete that as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work either.

Comment: Welp out of ideas, either you didn't install selenium correctly (which I doubt since you would get a different error message, or that there's a selenium.py(c) floating around that interfering with it.

Comment: Well I appreciate the attemp MooingRawr!

Comment: I would try the suggestions in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29092970/404469) including this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50641487/404469) which involves uninstalling selenium and reinstalling an older version to support the version of Python you are using.