# selenium cannot import name webdriver in ubuntu

Tags: python, selenium, ubuntu, webdriver

I have installed `selenium` in Ubuntu and by writing this code

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.chrome()
driver.get("https://google.com")
```

I have got this output

> ImportError: cannot import name webdriver

What should I do?

Comment: Check, if this helps you to solve the problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29092970

Answer (score 0):

Selenium is clearly found but wedbdriver can't be imported.
My guess is that you have a file called selenium too, in which case you should name it something else, because python tries to import webdriver from that file rather than the selenium package