# ImportError: cannot import name 'wedriver' from 'selenium'

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Just started working on selenium. I installed selenium through pip install selenium and once done tried to import web driver from selenium, but getting an error:-
ImportError: cannot import name 'wedriver' from 'selenium' (C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium_*init*_.py)

[Installed Selenium](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzlu7.png)

[Erorr Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lotSp.png)

I have tried solutions in the thread --> [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29092970/importerror-cannot-import-name-webdriver), but still the same.

Could anyone please solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your problem is the name you're missing a `b`

you are trying to install `wedriver` which doesn't exists.

try instead:

```
from selenium import webdriver
```

Comment: Thanks, I just figured that out and it's working. Thanks for your help though. Also, seems this keyoard needs to be changed :)