# cannot import name SQLAgent from langchain

Tags: python, python-3.x, langchain

Trying to query Oracle database using Python->langchain->SQLAlchemy->oracledb. Using Openai with langchain.

The code is below:

```
import os
import oracledb
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv
#from langchain.agents import SQLAgent
#from langchain_community import SQLAgent
from langchain_experimental import SQLAgent
from langchain_openai import OpenAI

load_dotenv(find_dotenv(), override=True)

username = os.environ.get("PYTHON_USERNAME")
password = os.environ.get("PYTHON_PASSWORD")

cp = oracledb.ConnectParams()
cp.parse_connect_string(os.environ.get("PYTHON_CONNECTSTRING"))

engine = create_engine(
    f'oracle+oracledb://{username}:{password}@{cp.host}:{cp.port}/?service_name={cp.service_name}'
)

sql_client = SQLAgent(engine)

llm = OpenAI(temperature=0.7, max_tokens=100, key=os.environ.get("OPENAI_API_KEY"))

chain = SQLAgent.build_chain(llm, sql_agent=sql_client)

while True:
    user_query = input("Enter your question about the schema (or 'quit' to exit): ")

    if user_query.lower() == "quit":
        break

    user_query = user_query.strip()  # Basic sanitization

    response = chain.run(user_query, print_results=True)
```

The error is below:

```
C:\Users\HI\Desktop\New folder\langchain>C:\Users\HI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe  scratch.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HI\Desktop\New folder\langchain\scratch.py", line 7, in <module>
    from langchain_experimental import SQLAgent
ImportError: cannot import name 'SQLAgent' from 'langchain_experimental' (C:\Users\HI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\langchain_experimental\__init__.py)
```

The connection to Oracle database using SQLAlchemy is done using a .env file and is successful.

```
C:\Users\HI\Desktop\New folder\streamlit\langchain>pip show langchain
Name: langchain
Version: 0.1.11

C:\Users\HI\Desktop\New folder\streamlit\langchain>pip show langchain_experimental
Name: langchain-experimental
Version: 0.0.53

C:\Users\HI\Desktop\New folder\streamlit\langchain>pip show langchain_openai
Name: langchain-openai
Version: 0.0.8
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: cannot import name 'webdriver'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29092970/importerror-cannot-import-name-webdriver)

Comment: Have you tried reading the [`langchain` Agents documentation](https://python.langchain.com/docs/use_cases/sql/agents)? In the documentation, they use `from langchain_community.agent_toolkits import create_sql_agent`

Comment: line 23 and line 27 are using SQLAgent. What should I replace the call to SQLAgent with?

Comment: You either read the package documentation and try to solve it yourself or wait for an expert who knows how to use the package to provide an answer (which may take a while).